# Hadoop remote data sources connectivity

Tags: hadoop

What are the available hadoop remote data sources connectivity options?

I know about drivers for MongoDB, MySQL and Vertica connectivity but my question is what are other available data sources that have driver for hadoop connectivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the few I am aware of :

Oracle

ArcGIS Geodatabase

Teradata

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW)

PostgreSQL

IBM InfoSphere warehouse

Couchbase

Netezza

Tresata

But I am still wondering about the intent of this question. Every data source fits into a particular use case. Like, Couchbase for document data storage, Tresata for financial data storage and so on. Are you going to decide your store based on the connector availability??I don't think so.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. No, I wanted to know about Hadoop connectivity capabilities for an internal project pitch.

Answer (score 0):

Your list will be too long to be useful.

Just one reference: [cascading](http://www.cascading.org/) gives you access to almost anything you want to access. More, you're not limited with Java. For example there is [scalding](https://github.com/twitter/scalding) component which provides very good framework for [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) programmers.